# Access function within key:value array

Tags: javascript

For a given constant that defines functions as below:

```
const foo = (state) => ({
    bar1: (count) => { }
    bar2: (item, count) => { }
})

const fooGenerate = () => {
    let state = {
        apples: 20,
        fruitList: []
    }
    return Object.assign(
        state,
        foo(state)
    )
}
```

I would like the function defined by bar2 to be able to call bar1. I have tried various combinations of `foo[bar1(count)]` or `foo[bar1](count)` or `bar1(count)` but none of them seem to work. Is there a way to do this? I recognize I could just call it from the assigned object like so:

```
newobject.bar2(item, count);
newobject.bar1(count);
```

But ideally I would like bar2 to automatically call bar1 from within the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with variables:

```
const foo = (state) => {
  var bar1 = (count) => { };
  var bar2 = (item, count) => { bar1() }
  return { bar1, bar2 };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
const foo = (state) => ({
    bar1: function(count) { console.log('bar1') },
    bar2: function(item, count) { this.bar1() }
})

foo().bar2();
```

The power of `this` ;)

Comment: `this` refers to the `bar2` function not to the object returned by `foo`.

Comment: Nope, In this situation `this` refers to the object where the function is placed.

Comment: No problem, `this` confuses me of often also ;)